# Adding points to bar graph

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I made a bar graph using the following code:

```
ifng <- c(156.81700, 51.014300, 34.239900)
barplot(ifng, main="Ifng", xlab="Level", ylab="Concentration", 
     names.arg=c("WT-250", "WT-50", "WT-10"), col="darkblue")
```

[image]

I would like to add a line to the `barplot` with data points of `150`, `50`, and `35` that correspond to the bar for `WT-250`, `WT-50`, and `WT-10` respectively. This line will be a line of best fit so to speak to show the overall trend of the `barplot`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want one straight line over all bars? But with a categorical x axis that slope won't really be interpretable (and would be more likely to be misleading). Doesn't the height of the bars tell you all you need to know?

Comment: No, I'm trying to illustrate an overarching pattern that this data follows. Maybe a line isn't the best idea. Maybe just points or a stacked bar graph. In that case, how do I make a stacked bar graph so that the data points I have already in the barplot would be juxtaposed to concentrations of 150, 50, and 35 for WT-250, WT-50, and WT-10 respectively?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to stack exactly or where the values for 150 and 35 would be coming from.

Comment: The 150, 50, and 35 come from an algorithm that would predict the concentration level within some degree of error. You can see my data points weren't exactly that so I want stacked bars that illustrate the differences